# Unresolved function or method post() Express 4.x Router

Tags: node.js, post, express

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var messages = [];

router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});

// Method 1
router.route('/send')
    .all(function (req, res, next) {
        next();
    })
    .post('/send', function (req, res) { // unresolved function or method post()
        console.log("Message sent");
        var msg = req.body.message;
        if (msg != '') {
            messages.push(msg);
        }
        res.redirect('/');
    });

// Method 2
router.post('/send', function (req, res) { // unresolved function or method post()
    console.log("Message sent");
    var msg = req.body.message;
    if (msg != '') {
        messages.push(msg);
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

I am trying to send a request using the `POST` method but I keep getting "**Unresolved function or method .post()**".

I tried to do the same as in the Express documentation : [Express Router](http://expressjs.com/api.html#router)

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think that this is not related to node but to intellij idea. Do you use intellij?

Comment: Yes. I will try another editor.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see that seems out of place is the `'/send'` parameter in your `.post`. You are already referencing the route in `router.route('/send')`. See [router.route() reference](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.route)

Try this:

```
router.route('/send')
    .all(function (req, res, next) {
        next();
    })
    .post(function (req, res, next) { 
        console.log("Message sent");
        var msg = req.body.message;
        if (msg != '') {
            messages.push(msg);
        }
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Comment: still undefined :/ I don't get, it's exactly what the docs say

Comment: What version of node? Version of Express? Running your original code resulted in an error for me. After fixing it like I did above no errors were produced.